# how to interpret scoverage.xml report

Tags: xml, scala, code-coverage, scoverage

I am using the scoverage in Scala project. During the build, I generate coverage HTML and XML reports.
I need to parse the XML file (i.e. `scoverage.xml`) to extract metrics for each class on:
* lines coverage: number of covered ones vs total
* statements coverage: number of covered ones vs total
* branches coverage: number of covered ones vs total
* functions coverage: number of covered ones vs total

Looking at the scoverage repo, I see that the report is generated by [ScoverageXmlWriter.scala](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/blob/master/scalac-scoverage-plugin/src/main/scala/scoverage/report/ScoverageXmlWriter.scala) but it is not documented!!

So here is an example output of the statement `tag`:

```
<statement package="<package>" class="<class>" class-type="Object" full-class-name="<package>.<class>" source="/path/to/<package>/<class>.scala" method="compileScala" start="350" end="350" line="18" branch="false" invocation-count="1" ignored="false">
</statement>
```

What does the attribute means?
Is `line` corresponding to the line number in the file? and what's `start` and `end` stands for?

Comment: I had the same questions a couple of years ago when writing [this](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mwz/sonar/scala/scoverage/ScoverageReportParser.scala). Maybe you will find that code easier to read / understand?

Comment: Nice, I will check it out.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez do you know what's `statement-rate`? is it percentage of covered statements, i.e. if I multiply it by `statement-count` I get the count of covered statements?

Comment: According to my code, yeah it is the percentage of statements covered by your tests in that file. For the count of covered statements I used `statements-invoked` but I guess the multiplication should give a similar result. - In any case, remember I wrote that code more than 2 years ago, I hardly remember what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers in the sbt plugin code itself [coverage.scala#L159-L168](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/blob/master/scalac-scoverage-plugin/src/main/scala/scoverage/coverage.scala#L159-L168)

```
  def invokedStatements: Iterable[Statement] = statements.filter(_.count > 0)
  def invokedStatementCount = invokedStatements.size
  def statementCoverage: Double = if (statementCount == 0) 1 else invokedStatementCount / statementCount.toDouble
  def statementCoveragePercent = statementCoverage * 100
  def statementCoverageFormatted: String = twoFractionDigits(statementCoveragePercent)
  def branches: Iterable[Statement] = statements.filter(_.branch)
  def branchCount: Int = branches.size
  def branchCoveragePercent = branchCoverage * 100
  def invokedBranches: Iterable[Statement] = branches.filter(_.count > 0)
  def invokedBranchesCount = invokedBranches.size
```

I simply had to parse the XML while considering the snippet above to recalculate the counts (e.g. branches count vs covered).